# How do Unix capabilities work?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel

it seems that starting kernel 2.2, they introduced the concept of **Capabilities**. According to the unix man page on capabilities, it says if you're not a root user, you can grant yourself of capabilities by calling cap_set_proc per thread basis. So does this mean that if you're writing a malware for unix, do you just grant yourself bunch of capabilities and compromise the system? If not, how does one grant capabilities required to run the program?

it seems that Unix's security model is quite <strike>flawed</strike> primitive. Am I getting this right?

I'll go more specific:

How do you (when running as a non-root user) send a signal to another process that is running under different user? On signal man page, it says you need CAP_KILL capability to perform this. However, reading the capabilities man page, I'm not sure how I can grant a process that capability.

Comment: Oh wow.. how is this off topic? could someone who voted to close this question please explain?

Comment: Seems that http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: This question is *absolutely* on-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's impossible. Use Socket or File instead.

Answer (score 1):

From [man cap_set_proc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_set_proc):

> Please note, by default, the only processes that have CAP_SETPCAP available to them are processes started as a kernel-thread. (Typically this includes init(8), kflushd and kswapd). You will need to recompile the kernel to modify this default.

Trust me if it was that easy I'm sure someone would have exploited it by now. Unix's security model may be simple by comparison to other operating systems, but it doesn't mean it's "flawed".

Comment: Okay so you're telling me that it's so primitive that the only way to grant capabilities is to modify the kernel?

Comment: No, I'm saying that most processes in Unix will never ever need to modify capabilities, so few in fact that the "permitted" processes are hard coded into the kernel. The rest of the processes abide by the normal security model, which doesn't rely on capabilities.